# Easier way to find where in jq code an error occurred?

Tags: debugging, jq

**Is there a way for jq to give a reference to *where* in code an error occurred?**

Too often I end up with errors that are unhelpful. Here is an example:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:43913): Cannot index object with null
```

With or without the --slurp flag, the line indicator for stdin is almost always the last line of input.  What would be really helpful is to note where in the code it failed at runtime.

Wrapping code snippets in try/catch blocks with `$__loc__` have proven unhelpful too, as the line in the code tends to be the catch block, not where the error occurred.

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:43913) (not a string): {"file":"<top-level>","line":68}
```

**Is there some method to make debugging jq scripts easier?**

What I've been doing instead is commenting out large chunks of code and performing a binary search for what code gets the error.  It feels like there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, using gojq ("the Go implementation of jq") gives good insights about errors.

Otherwise, you will probably find that some combination of `debug` statements, `$__loc__`, and debugging functions defined using `debug` to be most helpful.

Consider, for example:

```
def debug(msg): (msg|debug) as $debug | . ;
```

(The subtlety here is that you can use `"\(.)"` in `msg`.)

In a pinch, the command-line option `--debug-trace` can be useful.